# Find max number in array and return object name

Tags: javascript, arrays

I need to write a function mostExpensiveItemName(items), find the highest priced item in the array and return the items name. I think I need to use the Math.max() method but I'm not sure how to do it properly.

Here's the array:

```
let items = [
  {
    itemName: "Effective Programming Habits",
    type: "book",
    price: 13.99
  },
  {
    itemName: "Creation 3005",
    type: "computer",
    price: 299.99
  },
  {
    itemName: "Finding Your Center",
    type: "book",
    price: 15.00
  }
]
```

What I have so far is setting up the function and for loop:

```
    function mostExpensiveItemName(items) {
  let most = items.reduce((total, items) => items.price > total.price ? items : total);
  if (items.itemName === 0) {
    return undefined;
  }
  return most.itemName;
}
```

Example output:

```
mostExpensiveItemName(items) //=> "Creation 3005"
```

I figure I need to loop through the array, use Math.max() to find highest value, then return the string?

Comment: If you use `Math.max` you can get the highest price, but not the entire record associated with it. `Math.max(...items.map(x => x.price))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd go with [`Array.prototype.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce):

```js
const mostExpensiveItem = items.reduce(
    (carry, item) => item.price > carry.price ? item : carry
);

console.log(mostExpensiveItem.itemName); // "Creation 3005"
```

You can use it in your function, including returning `undefined` for empty `items`, as such:

```js
function mostExpensiveItemName(items) {
    if (items.length === 0) return undefined;
    
    return items.reduce(
        (carry, item) => item.price > carry.price) ? item : carry
    ).itemName;
}
```

You could also just do `return;` instead of `return undefined;`, but personally I think in this case it's nice to have it explicit.

Comment: So I made some adjustments to make sure I followed the instructions, and I'm passing most of the tests however, I'm getting an error message saying, "if there are no items in the array passed in, your mostExpensiveItemName should return undefined." I'm not exactly sure how to return undefined..

Answer (score 0):

```js
var items = [
  {
    itemName: "Effective Programming Habits",
    type: "book",
    price: 13.99
  },
  {
    itemName: "Creation 3005",
    type: "computer",
    price: 299.99
  },
  {
    itemName: "Finding Your Center",
    type: "book",
    price: 15.00
  }
]

items.sort(function (a, b) {
  return b.price- a.price;
});

console.log('test',items[0].itemName)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use [Array.prototype.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) in order to achieve that. For example:

```js
let items = [
  {
    itemName: "Effective Programming Habits",
    type: "book",
    price: 13.99
  },
  {
    itemName: "Creation 3005",
    type: "computer",
    price: 299.99
  },
  {
    itemName: "Finding Your Center",
    type: "book",
    price: 15.00
  }
];

function mostExpensiveItemName(items) {
  if (items.length === 0) {
    return undefined;
  }
  
  let maxPriceItem = items.reduce((a, b) => a.price > b.price ? a : b);
  
  return maxPriceItem.itemName;
}



console.log(mostExpensiveItemName(items));
console.log(mostExpensiveItemName([]));
```

Comment: Okay this is great. I made some adjustments to my initial bit of code however I am getting the error message, "if there are no items in the array passed in, your mostExpensiveItemName should return undefined." How do I return undefined?